# Two views with the same weight in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In the following code, I use the combination of layout_weight=1 and layout_width (or layout_height) equals to 0 in LinearLayout. 
One problem is why in the second LinearLayout, the second button and the first button do not occupy equal space ? They have the same weight (layout_weight=1) so they should have the same space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="wreoiwe roiwej roiwejr weoirjweoirjwoeirjoweijrowerjowejorjweoirjwoeiwoi" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Submit" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Cancelrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the second `LinearLayout` is `wrap_content` and that's not how `layout_weight` works.

From the docs:

> A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

With your `LinearLayout` at `wrap_content` and not filling the whole screen, there is no more "remaining space" in the parent view. Everything is simply as big as it should be. It will not expand the smaller of the buttons because with the parent at `wrap_content` there is no more space to expand into.

You can test this by changing the 2nd `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` and you will see the buttons each take half of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have one line with the textview and the next line the two bottons occupying the 50% of the total width you have to put on your second linearlayout

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`